# Pushing sensor generated data to Google Cloud Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-cloud-platform, iot

I'm working on a project where a device called Eyedro senses information such as voltage and current and uploads it to a cloud function which is already set up. The device comes with its own interface for reading the generated data, and I have the code it uses to do so. I need help using the code to take the generated data and sending it up to the cloud. I am a beginner and I don't know how to go about solving this problem so any type of direction will be greatly appreciated. Here is the code used to get the data and print it onto an HTML table.

```
  window.onload=function(){
    var data=[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]];
    update=function(data){
        var WattageSum=0;
        for (var j=0;j<2;j++){
            var PowerFactor=data[j][0]/1000;
            document.getElementById(j+'f').innerHTML=PowerFactor.toFixed(3);
            var Voltage=data[j][1]/100;
            document.getElementById(j+'v').innerHTML=Voltage.toFixed(3);
            var Amperage=data[j][2]/1000;
            document.getElementById(j+'i').innerHTML=Amperage.toFixed(3);
            var Wattage=data[j][3];
            document.getElementById(j+'p').innerHTML=Wattage.toFixed(0);
            WattageSum += Wattage;
        }
        var timer=setTimeout(function(){
            var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (xhttp==null){
                timer=setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(true); }, 3000);
                return;
            }
            xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (this.readyState==4){
                    if (this.status==200){
                        var json=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        update(json.data);
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Error ('+this.status+') requesting data from server.');
                    }
                }
            };
            xhttp.open('POST', 'http://192.168.0.134:8080/getdata', true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhttp.send();
        }, 2000);
        window.onunload=function(){
            if (timer!=null){
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
        }
    };
    update(data);
};
```

Thank you

Comment: You mentioned in the post that you already have a Cloud Function set up, so I am not understanding what do you mean by the following: "  take the generated data and sending it up to the cloud". Could you please explain where do you want to save the data and if you are getting the data from Eyedro successfully in the Cloud Function? In this case, are your getting any error? please share it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

So please follow the next steps to send your Eyedro Device data to the **Google Cloud Platform.**

1. Use [**Google Cloud IoT Core**](https://cloud.google.com/iot-core) to connect, manage, and ingest data from your device using common protocols (MQTT and HTTP).

- So, create a Cloud IoT Core registry of devices following the [Cloud IOT Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart).

2. Cloud IoT Core uses **Cloud Pub/Sub underneath** to aggregate dispersed device data into a single global system that integrates seamlessly with Google Cloud data analytics services. So you can use the Cloud Pub/Sub topic to receive data from Cloud IoT Registry.

- When you are creating the **Cloud IOT Registry**, there you have an option to [create a Pub/Sub topic](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart#create_a_device_registry). So `In the Default telemetry topic` dropdown list, select ``Create a topic```.
- Otherwise, you can also create a Topic in **Pub/Sub** separately and then associate it to your **Cloud IoT Registry.**
- You can also create a [**Cloud Pub/Sub Subscription**](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart#run_a_nodejs_sample_to_connect_a_virtual_device_and_view_telemetry) if you want to read some data from the Topic.

3. Then we can use [**Cloud Functions**](https://cloud.google.com/functions), which can be configured to execute based on many different triggers and events. One of those triggers are new data inserted on a PubSub Topic, so we will listen to our Topic associated with our **Device Registry**, and with each data that arrives we execute the function that will store the data in **BigQuery**.

> - To store the data in BigQuery, create a [Dataset and a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-web-ui#create_a_dataset) in BigQuery.

**Create a [Cloud Function with Trigger
Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub).**

- Click on Create Function, select Pub/Sub Topic as **Trigger**.
- Choose the topic we created before associated with Cloud IoT Registry.
- Using the following code, you can then upload the data inserted in **Pub/Sub to BigQuery**.

```
var BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery'); 
var projectId = 'PROJECT_ID'; 
 
var bigquery = new BigQuery({ 
  projectId: projectId, 
}); 
 
var datasetName = 'DATASET_NAME'; 
var tableName = 'TABLE_NAME'; 
 
exports.pubsubToBQ = function(event, callback) { 
  var msg = event.data; 
  var data = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(msg.data, 'base64').toString()); 
  bigquery 
    .dataset(datasetName) 
    .table(tableName) 
    .insert(data) 
    .then(function() { 
      console.log('Inserted rows'); 
      callback(); // task done 
    }) 
    .catch(function(err) { 
      if (err && err.name === 'PartialFailureError') { 
        if (err.errors && err.errors.length > 0) { 
          console.log('Insert errors:'); 
          err.errors.forEach(function(err) { 
            console.error(err); 
          }); 
        } 
      } else { 
        console.error('ERROR:', err); 
      } 
 
      callback(); // task done 
    }); 
};
```

- In the previous code, we are using Nodejs to insert data into our BigQuery table. Please update `projectId`, `datasetName`, and `tableName` in the previous code to your ones.
- Then add the following requirements in package.json file :

```
{
 "name": "cloud_function", 
 "version": "0.0.1", 
 "dependencies": { 
  "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^1.0.0" 
 } 
}
```

- Click on **Deploy** and this will deploy your **Cloud Function**.

4. Finally this function will be called when the data event occurs. You can see requests coming to the Cloud Function in your **Cloud Function Graph.**
5. Also you can see your data in **BigQuery** by going to ``Preview Section```of your table or by running the following query in **BigQuery SQL Editor**:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset_name.table_name
```

### Summary:

You will send your data to **Cloud IoT Core**, then the data is sent to **Cloud Pub/Sub Topic**. Once the data reached to Pub/Sub topic, a **Cloud Function** is triggered and the data is uploaded to **BigQuery**.

Please also have a look into the following [tutorial](https://hub.packtpub.com/build-google-cloud-iot-application/) and this [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/build-a-weather-station-using-google-cloud-iot-core-and-mongooseos-7a78b69822c5)